# Is there a yum command line switch to be informed whether a reboot is necessary after updating?

Tags: linux, updates, yum

I know that the `packagekit` GUI can inform the user that a reboot is necessary after an update.  But is there a `yum` switch I can turn on, or another terminal command I can use, to know whether a reboot is necessary?  (After all, `packagekit` must be getting its information somehow.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are levels of "necessary".  For anything that changes the kernel, it's necessary in order to take effect.  Some other things will just create annoyances until you reboot.  For example, many kinds of updates on my machine affect the screen saver so that it doesn't display its pretty pattern.  Everything that can be affected by an update doesn't always trigger a reboot message, so the mechanism isn't completely reliable, except to alert you to cases where the update won't take effect until reboot.

Comment: Shared library, non-kernel updates will apply to newly started processes but existing processes will still use the old library (which file they have open, whether it still has a directory entry or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kernel updates will require a reboot to take effect. There's a bash script at [How can I check from the command line if a reboot is required on RHEL or CentOS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/122178/how-can-i-check-from-the-command-line-if-a-reboot-is-required-on-rhel-or-centos) for checking if a reboot is needed because an update to the kernel has been installed. See [Re: How do you know when a reboot is required after yum update?](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-list/2009-July/msg00195.html) for reasons a reboot is usually not required for other updates.

Answer (score -1):

@moonpoint is right that kernel updates will require a reboot to take affect. However in any case if you are about to fix a Bug, Vulnerability or performance enhancement in any package, typically that will need a system reboot(or at least the service reboot) to be patched properly.

`needs-restarting` is a program that reports a list of process ids that started running before they or some component that they use were updated. This package is part of `yum-utils` and works perfect on Red Hat Distribution Versions 6 and 7.

Below is the sample after running a `yum upgrade` and `goferd` service being upgraded which requires the **service restart** to complete the upgrade process.

```
[root]# needs-restarting
1161 : python /usr/bin/goferd --foreground
```

After restarting the service

```
[root]# service goferd restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart goferd.service
[root]# needs-restarting
[root]#
```

Comment: This won't tell you whether the server needs to reboot.